# back button on video view

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I want to return to the first activity when I tapped back
first activity = Home
Second activity = Videos
here's the code:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));
```

I want to return to the first activity can somebody teach me how to do it?

Comment: you can finish your current activity when you click on back button.

Comment: You do have a backbutton ???? AttachOnClickListener to that button and just call finish from there simple.

Comment: I've done it. it doesn't work

Comment: I've done this it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onBackPressed(){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Back Pressed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
this.finish();
```

}

On pressing back a `Toast` is shown and the `Activity` finishes.